# Remove "Try for free" from login screen

Tags: login, app

I'm in the process of submitting an app using salesforce login to the apple store. However it got rejected due to external subscriptions.

The trigger for this is the "Try for free" button which opens a registration page for a trial account in the app.
This is considered a violation of [Apples guidelines (3.1.1 In App Payments)](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase).

[image: Salesforce login screen]

We use a WKWebView and the salesforce login url so it is not an element on our site, its from the login page from salesforce.

Is there a way to remove this button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2: Issue was resolved and accepted by Apple**

After some digging in the documentation I found the `display` parameter for the authorization url: [Docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5).

Description of the `display` parameter:

> Changes the display type of the login and authorization pages. Salesforce supports these values.

> - page—Full-page authorization screen (default).
> - popup—Compact dialog optimized for modern web browser popups.
> - touch—Mobile-optimized dialog designed for modern mobile devices, >such as Android and iPhone.
> - mobile—Mobile-optimized dialog designed for less capable devices, >such as BlackBerry operating system 5.

I used the `touch` value and resubmitted a new build of the app.

**Update 1: Apple changed their mind and rejected it again, writing the explanation below did not solve the issue sadly.**

After writing with the Apple Review Team the issue was resolved and no changes were needed.

Here's what I wrote:

Dear Apple Team,

regarding issue 3.1.1 Buisness Payments I understand that this is coming from the Salesforce Registration Page.
The "Try for free" button which is leading to the registration page is part of the Salesforce login provider.
This is not unlocking features in the app itself. Is this a violation to 3.1.1?

Best
Tim

Comment: Can you edit your answer and post exactly what you sent to them? Would be handy for others!

Comment: @MattLacey I've added the Text, good idea!

Comment: Nice one - not sure why you got downvoted on this - guessing some people think it's not relevant to Salesforce development but it's 100% a part of a developer's experience when working with Salesforce on iOS! Please do stick around :)